# How to filter soft deleted items in Spring Data's findAll() method?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Recently i learned there is `@Where` annotation, and i can successfully use it on my `@Entity` class. Looks like this filter will be applied in to every query.
And i faced the problem when i try to get this soft-deleted entity as element of collection in another @Entity.

> Unable to find SoftDeletedEntity with id xx (through reference chain ...

Now i want to try to use this @Where filter only on SpringData repo's `findAll()` method. I tried the following, but it did not work.

```
    public interface MyEntity extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

    @Where(clause = "is_deleted = 'false'")
    @Override
    List<MyEntity> findAll();
}
```

Is it possible at all?

Comment: I don't think so. To use Querydsl use it in the name method directly, something like that: findAllByIsDeletedFalse() -> See: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.named-queries `@Where(clause = "is_deleted = 'false'")` is the same as `findAllByIdIsDeletedFalse()`

Comment: `List<MyEntity> findByIsDeletedFalse();` should work in Spring Data JPA

Answer (score 5):

If you use hibernate and @Where, there's no easy solution to your question(it's filtered by Hibernate, not spring data).
But you can consider another approach to do soft delete and query with spring data's expression language:

```
@Override
@Query("select e from #{#entityName} e where e.deleteFlag=false")
public List<T> findAll();

//recycle bin
@Query("select e from #{#entityName} e where e.deleteFlag=true")
public List<T> recycleBin(); 

@Query("update #{#entityName} e set e.deleteFlag=true where e.id=?1")
@Modifying
public void softDelete(String id); 
//#{#entityName} will be substituted by concrete entity name automatically.
```

Rewrite base repository like this. All sub repository interfaces will have soft delete ability.

Comment: If all your objects has to have soft delete ability it is ok, but what if you want this soft delete ability for only a single object? The others are just deleted from the database.
Then the answer is Pau's comment: findAllByIsDeletedFalse() in the DAO of the object.

Comment: Did anyone face JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException with this way of retrieving Page'd data using PagingAndSortingRepository ?